# Grant access to third party lambda function to write into my Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have this third party company that developed a solution that's currently writing some data in a Redshift hosted by their account using lambda function X p.e., what I need now is to grant access to that lambda function X to write into a redshift owned by my account.

How can we make this work out ?

By what i searched prior to this, i think involves IAM Role but i'm not sure.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be to generate a database user login that the third-party can use:

- Use the [CREATE USER](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_USER.html) command to create a new database user, with a password specified
- Use [GRANT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_GRANT.html) and [REVOKE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_REVOKE.html) to allocate the minimum level of necessary permission to the new user (eg can only update specific tables, cannot query any other tables)
- Provide the third-party with the username and password to use in their Lambda function
- Configure the **Security Group** on the Redshift cluster to permit access to the [range of Lambda addresses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html) used in the region where the third-party is running their Lambda function — this is not perfect because it still leaves the Security Group open to a wide range of attacks, but it is better than leaving it publicly accessible

However, from a security perspective, **it is not a good idea to allow any external parties direct access to your database**. There could be potential access to confidential or Personally Identifiable Information that can leak out this way. A more secure architecture than the above would be something where the third-party sends their data to your system for processing, rather than having direct access to your database.

Some examples:

- The third-party could **upload a file to your Amazon S3 bucket**, which can then trigger a Lambda function in your own account to load the data into Redshift, *or*
- Data could be sent to an **Amazon Kinesis stream** (good for continuous data loading) or **Amazon SQS**, and a Lambda function in your own account could then load that data into Redshift, *or*
- Use **API Gateway** to create an interface through which the third-party can send their data, which would then trigger a Lambda function in your own account to load that data into Redshift